# Taking payment on a website

Tags: php, payment

Whats the recommended way to do this with Paypal (i've heard they're a nightmare to deal with).

Ideally the user would sign up with credit card details and then i'd process the payments through their banks? Is that how it works? With API's?

Comment: Paypal has a big developer site and community: http://x.com

Comment: The reason people are willing to put up with the big chunk of the payment that Paypal takes is that trying to do it yourself is hideously complicated and difficult.

Comment: I'd like to know where you heard that PayPal was a nightmare to deal with.  Out of all of the payment gateway providers I've used, they are by far the easiest to integrate with, and the one I would trust the most.

Comment: @Paul, how much do they take?

Comment: @Andrew, it's a few percent plus a fixed amount (you can look up the exact amounts on-line) which means if it's a small amount to start with, you get kind of hosed.  I think out of $10, I end up getting something like $9.40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally the user would sign up with
>   credit card details and then i'd
>   process the payments through their
>   banks? Is that how it works?

No.  In a correctly designed system you never have access to your user's credit card number.  It's your payment processor (eg PayPal, MoneyBookers, FastSpring, etc.) that takes care of processing your customer's credit card.

So your customer is taken to the payment processor's site (on a page which can be customized to use your company's logo etc.) and then your payment processor warns you when a purchase a made (for example by calling a specific URL).

> With API's?

Yup, PayPal (and MoneyBookers and things like FastSpring) offer APIs for several languages (like Java APIs).

PayPal has a dev environment on which you can test these kind of functionalities, so does MoneyBookers if I recall correctly (also note that sometimes the dev environments are a bit buggy and/or down).

Comment: Commenting on my own answer...  FastSpring owns PayPal in many ways and, last I checked, allowed to pay by PayPal too (but not MoneyBookers last time I checked it).  They've got lots of docs/FAQs/tutorials/examples/etc.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Checked them out after reading your answer and was very impressed. Decent rates too.

Comment: @Andrew Heath: a very nice side effect of using FastSpring to accept PayPal is that in case of a dispute, PayPal takes FastSpring *very* seriously: they won't insta-close/insta-suspend your PayPal account if FastSpring is "fighting" a dispute for you.  There are too many horror stories about PayPal shutting down your account *then* deciding if they'll reopen it or not.  When using FastSpring, they do it for you: they contact PayPal, they fight for you.  (and, no, I don't work for them ; )

Comment: PayPal shut me down last month for making a routine Steam purchase on an IP geolocated to a state different from my bank account address (was traveling, needed a new fix). It was a pretty goddamn awful process. After 2 weeks of me sending hatemail they reactivated my account. So yeah, pumped to try FastSpring!

Comment: @Andrew Heath: but that is from a customer's point of view right? It's as a customer that PayPal screwed you, not as a vendor? FastSpring only helps you from the vendor point of view.  Having a PayPal account suspended as a customer is bad but having a PayPal account suspended as a vendor can be really devastating.

Comment: Correct, that was me as a PayPal customer. But I'm planning on doing a website fundraiser later this year, and I'm oh-so-thankful to have a valid alternative to PayPal since it's so easy to imagine the horrors of my ordeal on a business scale.

Comment: @Andrew Heath: yup... The really nice thing here is that you'll still allow your customers/donators to give money using PayPal but you won't have to deal directly with PayPal in case there's an issue.  FastSpring will do it for you.  Of course they take a small fee and altough small it's bigger than the fee other payment processors are taking but: no chargeback charges with FastSpring and they accept PayPal (and they "fight" PayPal for you in case there's an issue).  To me the higher fees of FastSpring are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal offers APIs for processing payments. Typically, the user is taken off your page to login into paypal and then paypal calls back to your site with approval/shipping info. The whole point is for the user to shield their credit card info from your site, making things safer.* You can use either the NVP (name-value pair) or SOAP protocol for development. There are also 3rd party libraries to simplify integration.

Check out the API reference here to get an idea:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

*PayPal does offer a Direct Payment API which allows your site to take credit cards directly and use PayPal as the gateway:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside